# Can't get email updates for Favorite Tags

Tags: bug, email, subscription, tag-watching

On the page https://stackexchange.com/filters/103309/favorite-tags there's a list of the questions that match my Watched Tags across all sites. I'd like to get these questions emailed to me instead of having to check the page. I used to be subscribed to some other tags, which worked fine, but I changed my mind and wanted to be subscribed to all my Watched Tags. So I clicked "Subscribe" on the Email Updates section on the right hand side of the page, entered my email address (and checked "every 3 hours") and hit "subscribe".

I didn't get a confirmation email and haven't been receiving any emails. I retried a few times in case I entered my address wrongly, but nothing worked.

Comment: For filters, you get an email confirmation thingy. I tried subscribing to a filter earlier, but I didn't get the email. If you don't click the link (or, indirectly, don't get the email), you won't get updates.

Comment: @PrincessOlivia Sure, the question is how to get the confirmation email.