# No "bounty expiring soon" notification

Tags: bug, status-norepro, bounties, notifications

Recently I offered a bounty and only got notifications 3/1 day before expiring and when the bounty was auto-awarded, but not at the start of the grace period (neither in the inbox nor by email, although other emails from stackexchange, like the rep recalculation mail, arrive just fine).

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319354

[image]

In the past, I found this reminder at the start of the grace period very helpful. Is this a bug or was it removed on purpose?

Comment: From what I remember, the "bounty expiring soon" in between those two only goes out via email and does not trigger an inbox notification. But I don't remember for certain.

Comment: @animuson I did not receive an email either

Comment: Verified, you were sent an email on Nov 7 at 0:00 UTC to notify that the grace period started.

Comment: @animuson Thanks for checking! Unfortunately no email arrived :(

Comment: Possible related to the problem of non-delivered email: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333966/cant-get-email-updates-for-favorite-tags https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337217/cannot-confirm-email-subscription https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330246/filter-subscription-email-is-not-being-delivered-june-july-2019-edition

Comment: setting to norepro. can't reproduce locally, hopefully was a one-time thing

Comment: @YaakovEllis Since https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330246/filter-subscription-email-is-not-being-delivered-june-2019-present-edition#comment1137297_340291 also does not work I doubt that this is a one-time thing :(

Comment: @samcarter both this case and the other case that you linked to are both failing due to specific things that having to do with your email domain that are out of our control.

Comment: @YaakovEllis I do get other mails from stackexchange, for example the rep-recalculation email arrived just fine. Why does my email work for these mails, but not for bounty notifications?

Comment: Update: works as of Feb 2020. Thanks a lot for finally fixing!

Answer (score 3):

It could be an issue with [New Post Notices rollout on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow) if it is on Stack Overflow as there were [some issues were bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337147/416943) (those were fixed but some issues may still remain).

You should also be sent an email, sometimes [the email may not be delivered](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/where-is-the-bounty-icon) and this is an issue with your email provider.