# Bounty notifications broken, in particular no notification at start of bounty grace period

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, notifications, expired-bounty

About an hour ago (April 1st, 12:03), the grace period for [a bounty of mine](https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/2862/revisions) ended (without me awarding an answer). I have the following notifications in my inbox for this bounty:

- Mar 28 at 11:03:

  > Your bounty on question {{title}} expires in three days.
- 2 days ago:

  > Your bounty on question {{title}} expires in one day.
- 1 hour ago:

  > Your bounty on question {{title}} has expired.

I did get an e-mail that the grace period started, but that was only 13 h ago (and no, it’s not an AM/PM confusion, I don’t use those).

There are several things wrong with this:

- Most importantly, there is no inbox notice when the bounty ends and the grace period starts (24.5 hours ago in the reference frame in question). This is the most important notice as this is when you usually want to start awarding the bounty. For [a bounty I awarded last week](https://academia.stackexchange.com/posts/61282/revisions) the same thing happened (according to my inbox history). This is probably also the reason for the confusion [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/56750/2594) (in the comments; in German).
- The e-mail is delayed by half a day.
- *Expire* is used inconsistently. The first two notices imply that expiration refers to the start of the grace period; in the last it refers to the end of the grace period. The latter makes more sense to me and I suggest to use *end* in the other notices instead.
- The notices all lack an article. Either use “on the question {{title}}” or just “on {{title}}”.

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337733/255554) is similar, but it reports a complete absence of the e-mail and was apparently fixed (as per the OP).

Comment: @Dev, it's become worse than described above: 1st you get a few days notification, then you get a 24 hour notification, then you are told it's expired with **no grace** period. Others, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7pid.jpg - a "going to expire in 6 hours" notice is handy (and never been available), an "expired 3 hours ago" notice (you shoulda been online) is less helpful; and no grace is new.

Comment: @Rob: The two notifications in your screenshots (if taken at the same time) are two days apart. It’s just the ambiguous use of *expire* that makes it seem otherwise. The grace period did happen; you were just not not notified about it.

Comment: @Rob: Sure, hence this bug report. I am just saying that your experience seems to agree with what I describe here. It has not become even worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notifications for the end-of-bounty / beginning-of-grace-period are now working once more.